# Parse de arquivo .txt usando Pandas a partir de regras externas em um JSON

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um conjunto de dados em formato .txt que tem uma formatação própria com as regras descritas por um arquivo JSON próprio separado.

Há alguma forma direta de indicar para o Pandas usar esse JSON como base pra decodificar o .txt?

Esse é um pedaço do arquivo .json  - ele tem vários objetos desse tipo, mas com coisas diferentes no value de cada key.

```
[
    {
      "codigo": "V0101",
      "inicio": 1,
      "tamanho": 4,
      "descricao": "Ano de referência",
      "rotulo": "ano",
      "valores": "str"
    },
    {
      "codigo": "UF",
      "inicio":5,
      "tamanho":2,
      "descricao": "Unidade da Federação",
      "rotulo": "UF",
      "valores": {"11": "Rondônia", "12": "Acre", "13": "Amazonas", "14": "Roraima", "15": "Pará", "16": "Amapá", "17": "Tocantins", "21": "Maranhão", "22": "Piauí", "23": "Ceará", "24": "Rio Grande do Norte", "25": "Paraíba", "26": "Pernambuco", "27": "Alagoas", "28": "Sergipe", "29": "Bahia", "31": "Minas Gerais", "32": "Espírito Santo", "33": "Rio de Janeiro", "35": "São Paulo", "41": "Paraná", "42": "Santa Catarina", "43": "Rio Grande do Sul", "50": "Mato Grosso do Sul", "51": "Mato Grosso", "52": "Goiás", "53": "Distrito Federal"}
    },
```

Esse é um print de parte do arquivo .txt - as linhas não são regulares :
[image]

Agradeço muito se puderem ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

```
def extrai_txt(arquivo, layout):
    for linha in arquivo:
        yield {c['codigo']: linha[c['inicio']-1:c['inicio']-1+c['tamanho']]
            for c in layout}
```

Forma de uso:

```
with open('seu_arquivo.txt') as f:
    for reg in extrai_txt(f, seu_json):
        print(reg)
```

O resultado são vários `dict`s:

```
{'ano': '2015', 'uf': '11', ...}
{'ano': '2016', 'uf': '13', ...}
```